# Why random number generated is not stored in variable

Tags: debugging, excel, vba

This is my code

```
Sub lab1()

Dim first As Integer
Dim third As Integer
Dim total As Integer

total = 0

For i = 0 To i = 99
    first = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)
    total = total + first
Next i

MsgBox (total)

End Sub
```

I am trying to generate 100 random numbers between 1 to 100 and store each number into the variable 'total'. I cant understand why the value of total is always like below 100 , it seems like that 'total' is only storing 1 random number not 100 random number

Comment: Try to review your code. I notice there is an error in your syntax.

Comment: @joseph please tell me which line, i am total new at VBA programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i = 0 To 99 << this is an important line to notice

```
Dim first As Integer
    Dim third As Integer

    Dim total As Integer


    total = 0

    For i = 0 To 99


    first = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)



    total = total + first

    Next i

    MsgBox (total)
```

Comment: i dont get you, whats the difference between my code and yours??

Comment: For i = 0 To 99 and For i = 0 To i = 99 << it will run only one time as you are looping only once

Answer (score 0):

VBA is expecting a number after the `To`, so the line `For i = 0 To i = 99` is interpreted as `For i = 0 To (i = 99)`, and since `i` has just been created with the value `0`, the expression `i = 99` equals to `False`, and the boolean value `False` is converted to `0`.

So the line `For i = 0 To i = 99` is interpreted as `For i = 0 To 0`.